# style the item of ListView in android with one TextField

Tags: android, listview, styles

In the android application, there is a list of events. Each event includes the datetime of event, event name, event price and event availbility. as you might see from the image [image]

what I do is to customize a adapter by extending the BaseAdapter class. as you simply know about it, right now what concerns me is how to style the datetime and price. One simple idea is to use multiple TextFields to style them each, another solution is to style the datetime/price with only one TextField.

In my mind, if there are more TextFields in the adapter, it takes more memory, in particular there are a lot of ListItems in the list, is it?

if my assumption is true, how can I style one TextField to make it looks like the image below